# In XCode 4 change output path and run mutiple targets

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to change the out put folder for where a target's executable and libraries are built to? Also is it possible to run more than one target at a time within XCode?

Answer (score 1):

You can change where Xcode places derived data from Xcode's Locations Preferences. Choosing File > Project Settings allows you to change the derived data location for a single project.

I don't know of any way to run multiple targets simultaneously in Xcode.